# Volatile example from Java Language Specification returning surprising behavior

Tags: java, volatile, jls

I wanted to try the [Java lang spec example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e10344) myself but there is apparently something I do not understand. My understanding was that the order of incrementing of volatile counters should be the same as it appears in the code. "Surprisingly" I am getting a random counter values in terms of that one counter is sometimes less, equal and greater than the other.
Is there anyone who could explain what I am missing?

The code and output below:

```
public class C {

private static volatile int i = 0;
private static volatile int j = 0;

static void one() {
    i++;
    j++;
}

static void two() {
    int a = i;
    int b = j;
    if(a < b)
        System.out.println(a + " < " + b);
    if(a > b)
        System.out.println(a + " > " + b);
    if(a == b)
        System.out.println(a + " = " + b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true)
                one();
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true)
                two();
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Output

```
214559700 > 214559699
214559807 > 214559806
214559917 > 214559916
214560019 = 214560019
214560137 > 214560136
214560247 = 214560247
214560349 > 214560348
214560455 = 214560455
214560561 > 214560560
214560670 = 214560670
214560776 = 214560776
214560886 > 214560885
214560995 = 214560995
214561097 < 214561098
```

Comment: What's surprising?  The increments always happen in order, but that doesn't mean that copying the values to `a` and `b` or the printing always happens after both things have been incremented.   Can you clarify what exactly you expected to happen?

Comment: Another thing to remember... even increment is not "atomic".  If you have two threads that are simultaneously calling i++ 1000 times, you will likely find that i is not 2000 when execution is complete, but some value less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all three scenarios, imagine we're starting with `i = 0` and `j = 0`... both one() and two() get to perform two operations, but the order between one and two is undefined:

**a == b**

```
two() loads i (a = 0)
two() loads j (b = 0)
one() increments i (i = 1)
one() increments j (j = 1)
```

**a > b**

```
one() increments i (i = 1)
two() loads i (a = 1)
two() loads j (b = 0)
one() increments j (j = 1)
```

**a < b** (rarer)

```
two() loads i (a = 0)
one() increments i (i = 1)
one() increments j (j = 1)
two() loads j (b = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the threads can be interleaved in a number of ways.  Since you're copying `i` and `j` into `a` and `b`, you can have modifications to `i` and `j` *between* copying `i` into `a` and `j` into `b`.  E.g., this sort of trace would explain your output:

#### Some initial state, then copy

- background: i == 214559700, j == 214559699
- T2: a = i, b = j

  ```
  214559700 > 214559699
  ```

#### Increment 7 times, then incre— copy! —ment

- T1: (i++ j++) (x7)
- T1: i++
- T2: a = i, b = j

  ```
    214559807 > 214559806
  ```
- T1: j++

#### Increment 9 times, then incre— copy! —ment

- T1: (i++ j++) (x9)
- T1: i++
- T2: a = i, b = j

  ```
  214559917 > 214559916
  ```
- T1: j++

#### Increment 2 times, then copy

- T1: (i++ j++) (x2)
- T2: a = i, b = j

  ```
  214560019 = 214560019
  ```

Comment: Thank you Joshua for the precise/practical answer! I probably did not ask my question right. The "surprising" thing is that I can observe the value of a being LESS than the value of b. In the specification there is:cite"

Comment: Spec: "This allows method one and method two to be executed concurrently, but guarantees that accesses to the shared values for i and j occur exactly as many times, and in exactly the same order, as they appear to occur during execution of the program text by each thread. Therefore, the shared value for j is never greater than that for i, because each update to i must be reflected in the shared value for i before the update to j occurs. It is possible, however, that any given invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is much greater..."

Comment: @user2991939 Right, the values of `i` and `j` are always such that `i ≥ j`, but, as you quoted, "any given invocation of method two might observe a value for **j** that is much greater".  The text explicitly calls out that method two might see a `j` (and thus store in `b` a value) that is _greater_, which means that the value of `a` is _lesser_.  I hope the explanation/transcript above showed how this can happen, i.e., how the incrementing and copying can be interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

The accesses to i and j are not synchronized, so, all the following cases can happen:

- t2 reads i, t2 reads j, t1 writes i, t1 writes j
- t2 reads i, t1 writes i, t2 reads j, t1 writes j
- t1 writes i, t2 reads i, t2 reads j, t1 writes j
- t1 writes i, t2 reads i, t2 reads j, t2 reads i, t2 reads j, t1 writes j
- etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

When one of the threads just finished incrementing `i` and wants to start to increment `j`, the other thread possibly has set the int's `a` and `b` already, thus resulting in different values.

`volatile` is of different use as I think you think it does. Essentially, `volatile` is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads. The volatile modifier guarantees that any thread that reads a field will see the most recently written value

Declaring a volatile Java variable means:

- The value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally: all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory";
- Access to the variable acts as though it is enclosed in a `synchronized` block, synchronized on itself.

[Source and more explanation.](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml)

The use of `volatile` becomes more clear when you want to access the same volatile members from different threads instead of different members.

Answer (score 0):

If we read `j` first,

```
static void two() {
    int b = j;
    int a = i;
```

then it is guaranteed that a>=b.